# Determine geolocation in shell / Terminal on OS X 10.5

Tags: terminal, leopard, command-line, geolocation

Is there a way to determine geolocation in shell / Terminal on OS X 10.5?

There's another question, [Is there a way to access a Mac's geolocation from terminal?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/60152/is-there-a-way-to-access-a-macs-geolocation-from-terminal-mountain-lion), but it seems to only be concerned with the currently-latest OS X 10.8.

Answer (score 2):

According to Apple Developer [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocation_Class/CLLocation/CLLocation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007126), the feature is available from OS X 10.6 or later.

Alternative to hardware-based GPS, how about DNS-based geolocation option for OSX 10.5? May be worth your time to google those.

Comment: A useful answer, this would confirm that indeed most tools from the 10.8 question would probably not work on 10.5 at all.  But it doesn't mean that determining the location itself is not possible on 10.5, e.g. through some other means or third-party tools that don't depend on `CoreLocation`.

Comment: Agree. Please post an answer to share if you know non-GPS but DNS-based solution.