# Get my computer's current city and state from terminal

Tags: geolocation

How can I get my computer's location to the granularity of `city` and  `country` using the command-line?

I know I could get the IP of the correct network interface and do an IP lookup but I wonder if the system has a quicker way to access this. The system clock has the location so I am wondering if it's possible to get it that way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Command line tool

I've made quick modification to an excellent [robmathers](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/60207/74657) app **WhereAmI**. You can find it on my [github](https://github.com/slozo/WhereAmI).

Once You compile it and run, that's the output:

```
Latitude: 40.714232
Longitude: -73.9612889
Accuracy (m): 65.000000
Timestamp: 30.04.2015, 11:37:45 CEST
Location: 277 Bedford Avenue, Brooklyn, NY 11211, United States
```

If You want only the city and the country - changes in parsing json should be made (or `grep` the output). Sample json data can be found [here](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=40.714224,-73.961452&sensor=true).

<sub>Note: This is very quick implementation, but there shouldn't be any errors</sub>

## Info from preferences

You can get info from preferences by running:

```
defaults read /Library/Preferences/.GlobalPreferences.plist com.apple.preferences.timezone.selected_city
```

You'll need to parse the output, because it looks like:

```
{
CountryCode = PL;
GeonameID = 3081368;
Latitude = "51.1";
LocalizedNames =     {
    pl = "Wroc\\U0142aw";
};
Longitude = "17.03333";
Name = "Wroc\\U0142aw";
Population = 634893;
TimeZoneName = "Europe/Warsaw";
Version = 1;
}
```

Comment: Well, this is awesome, but requires the internet. If I use that, I figure I might as well do an old-fashioned IP lookup. This is more accurate, I take it?

Comment: As far as I know, there's no offline database with locations assigned to lat/lon. The only thing I found is: `/System/Library/PreferencePanes/DateAndTime.prefPane/Contents/Resources/TimeZone.prefPane/Contents/Resources/all_cities_adj.plist` but that's only capital cities (?) list.

Comment: My clock does already know it's locale in order to set a time zone. Usually it even has the correct city. It knows this with or without internet connectivity, it just won't update the location without the internet.

Comment: @SimplGy the info is stored in `defaults`, updated the answer

Comment: That is so awesome!